# Calculate total time for which the value was 1 for a specified time period

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset with two columns. I need to calculate the total time in seconds for which the value was greater than 1 for the duration between 00:00 to 6:00. How can I do this in most efficient way in R? Can this be done using dplyr package? I need to do this in a generic way such that it can be applied for other durations(6 to 9, 9 to 12) as well. Below is some sample data :

```
+--------------------------------------+
|     Timestamp                 Value  |
+--------------------------------------+
| 2015-10-01 00:00:00            300   |
| 2015-10-01 00:00:55            200   |
| 2015-10-01 00:25:10            0     |
| 2015-10-01 01:05:40            876   |
| 2015-10-01 02:05:40            989   |
| 2015-10-01 04:05:40            0     |
| 2015-10-01 05:00:00            600   |
| 2015-10-01 06:00:00            300   |
+--------------------------------------+
```

So the output that is expected here for duration between 00 to 06 is 15910 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I would parse the date/time:

```
dat$Timestamp <- strptime(dat$Timestamp, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Then I would grab the seconds between each observation using `difftime`:

```
secs <- as.numeric(difftime(tail(dat$Timestamp, -1), head(dat$Timestamp, -1),
                            units="secs"))
```

Finally, I would sum up the number of seconds in each interval that has value greater than 1:

```
sum(secs[head(dat$Value, -1) > 1])
# [1] 15910
```

Assuming the boundaries of the time you are interested in appear in the Timestamp field, you can limit to the time range of interest (start at `begin.time` and end at `end.time`) with something like:

```
dat.subset <- dat[dat$Timestamp >= begin.time & dat$Timestamp <= end.time,]
```

Data:

```
dat <- data.frame(Timestamp = c("2015-10-01 00:00:00", "2015-10-01 00:00:55", "2015-10-01 00:25:10", "2015-10-01 01:05:40", "2015-10-01 02:05:40", "2015-10-01 04:05:40", "2015-10-01 05:00:00", "2015-10-01 06:00:00"), Value = c(300, 200, 0, 876, 989, 0, 600, 300))
```

Comment: There is more to this problem now. I have data for more than a year in the same format that was specified in my main question (Timestamp, Value). For each day there are different shifts (12 to 6, 6 to 9, etc.) I have extracted the data using xts/split function. What I need to do is lets say for the records between 12 to 6 for any particular day, if I have "NA" value for the first record of any shift ("00:00:00", NA) then I need to look up for the last record of the previous shift and use that same value for current record....

Comment: -------------------------------------+
|     Timestamp                 Value  |
2015-09-39  23:58:59            600
| 2015-10-01 00:00:00            NA  |
| 2015-10-01 00:00:55            200   |
| 2015-10-01 00:25:10            0     |
| 2015-10-01 01:05:40            876   |
| 2015-10-01 02:05:40            989   |
| 2015-10-01 04:05:40            0     |
| 2015-10-01 05:00:00            600   |
| 2015-10-01 05:55:00            300

Comment: @AspiringDataScientist it sounds like you're asking a new question now (how to impute missing values in a time series dataset). I would encourage you to use the "Ask Question" link at the top of the page to ask a new question, providing a link to this question if it provides useful context.

Comment: Similarly,towards the end of the shift, I need to check for the last timestamp of that shift. In this example(12 to 6), if the last timestamp that I have is at 2015-10-01 05:55:00 then I will assume that corresponding value is the same at 2015-10-01 06:00:00 and will add those 5 mins to my final result. So, the expected output is 15855.

Comment: @AspiringDataScientist It sounds like you could benefit from a better example dataset in your question. Perhaps you could edit it to capture these additional features of your question. Make sure to update the corresponding expected output.

Comment: I have raised a new question for this problem.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33022167/calculate-total-time-for-which-the-value-was-1-for-a-multiple-intervals